# Converting a byte [] to PrivateKey in java for digital signature

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, digest, sha1

I need to digitally sign a String using the SHA-1 digest algorithm first and then apply the RSA algorithm, using a PrivateKey to sign it. I already have the PrivateKey stored in my database as data type char(250) in base64. My problem is that I don't know how to convert it into a PrivateKey for using it for signing in:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(digest);
```

Digest was an array of bytes to which I applied the SHA-1 digest algorithm:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte [] ba = cadena.getBytes();
byte [] digest  = md.digest(ba);
```

That is the solution I thought about, but if anyone has a better solution I would appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you persisted the private key into the DB. But [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) provides some information on how to load a `KeyStore` from a file system, and retrieve the `Private` and `Public` keys.

Relevant code snippet (modified to suit your requirement) is,

```
   String password = ...;
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);

   byte[] keyAsByteArray = ...; // The key persisted in the DB
   InputStream keyStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyAsByteArray);
   ks.load(keyStream, password);
```

and then,

```
   KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS, password);  
   PrivateKey privateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
```

Comment: what is the key store type of 64 base encoding?

Comment: @user1084509 I don't think keystore type has anything to do with encoding. Encoding is a means of converting one form of data to another. Your keystore type may of one of the types mentioned [in this article (link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA)

Comment: Ok thank you, now I get it. I have another question regarding this line: KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS, password);... password is expected to be of the type KeyStore.ProtectionParameter, how can I do this casting? My password is an array of characters or a String.

Comment: @user1084509 You can create an instance of [`Keystore.PasswordProtection`(link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.PasswordProtection.html) with your password and pass it in.

Comment: I was reading the KeyStore API and it states that the `KeyStore` contains the privateKey accompanied by the certificate. In my case, I have the private key and the certificate in two separate byte arrays [] how can I use this?

Comment: @user1084509 [Ref (link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeyStore). Private keys have associated certificate [chain] that is used to authenticate the Public key. Check out `Keystore.setCertificateEntry(..)`. BTW, you need to construct the `Certificate` from `byte[]` in a similar way using `CertificateFactory` [Ref (link)](http://www.nealgroothuis.name/import-a-private-key-into-a-java-keystore/)