# Digital Signature in SOAP message

Tags: java, xml, soap, xml-serialization, digital-signature

I'm trying to create a SOAP message with signature (Russian GOST34.10-2001 algorithm) in Java for some goverment services. The thing is that the service tells me that Signature is invalid and I can't see where I made a mistake. The key container where I read private key and certificate from is valid.
Where things go wrong? I understand that my question is quite specific but I still hope that someone could show me the way.

update1:*a little update: body of message has some cyrillic(utf)-8 nodes and values*
update2:
So I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438857/converting-a-byte-to-privatekey-in-java-for-digital-signature) and tried to get the PrivateKey in the same way and got this Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: private key algorithm does not match algorithm of public key in end entity certificate

Here's some code:

Here I marshal classes into SOAP body:

```
try {
            MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage sm = mf.createMessage();
            SOAPPart sp = sm.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = sp.getEnvelope();

            QName bodyId = new QName("http://ws.unisoft/", "SendFullULRequest");

            SOAPBody sb = (SOAPBody) envelope.getBody();
            SOAPHeader sh = (SOAPHeader) envelope.getHeader();

            javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(FullULRq.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller();

            marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<FullULRq>(bodyId, FullULRq.class, fulr),
                    sm.getSOAPBody());

            sm.saveChanges();
```

Then I compute Digest Value:

```
ReferenceType rt2 = new ReferenceType();
            rt2.setURI("#body");
            ////Пункт 7
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(sm.getSOAPBody());
            Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
            try {
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
                transformer.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
                Init.init();

                Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
                final ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(canon.canonicalize(outputStream.toByteArray()));


                rt2.setDigestValue(computeDigestWithStream(is));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

With this method:

```
public static byte[] computeDigestWithStream(ByteArrayInputStream stream) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest digest =
            MessageDigest.getInstance("GOST3411");

    // processing data
    final DigestInputStream digestStream =
            new DigestInputStream(stream, digest);
    while (digestStream.available() != 0) {
        digestStream.read();
    }
```

And finally I generate a signature from the  block (in which  element is present):

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Source xmlSource2 = new DOMSource(sm.getSOAPBody());
        Result outputTarget2 = new StreamResult(outputStream2);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        transformer.transform(xmlSource2, outputTarget2);
        Init.init();
        Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
        InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream2.toByteArray());
        byte[] bb = canon.canonicalize(outputStream2.toByteArray());
        byte[] signval = sign("CryptoProSignature", key, bb);
```

sign() method:

```
public static byte[] sign(String algorithmName, PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        final Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(algorithmName);
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(data);
        return sig.sign();
    }
```

And if it is relevant this is how I read the privateKey from a container:

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("FloppyStore");

        String passwd = "*";
        String kalias = null; 

        ks.load(null, null);

        Enumeration enum1 = ks.aliases();
        for (; enum1.hasMoreElements();) {
            String tAlias = (String) enum1.nextElement();
            if (ks.isKeyEntry(tAlias)) {
                kalias = tAlias;
            }
            System.out.println(tAlias);
        }


        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(kalias, passwd.toCharArray());
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does `keytool -list Path_to_your_Floppystore.jks` list your private key properly? Did you keep the password for your keystore and private-key equal (-> recommended)? Why not using the WSS4J-library for your purpose?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. SOAP Server won't accept my signature, no matter which elements I modify. I'm sure Keys and Cert. are ok as you. I think that we're missing something on canonicalization or Attributes. Can you post more details about outputted XML?